# nginx não mostra index php

Tags: php, nginx, docker

Então caras acredito que seja alguma configuração no servidor que não esteja mostrando a página de erro, estou rodando um `docker-compose` que "sobe" um container *php,mysql e nginx* porém ao acessar o localhost me vem o seguinte erro:

-**403 Forbidden**

Segue o arquivo de configuração do nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

E o docker-compose pra tirar a curiosidade:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code/public_html:/code
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        links:
            - php
    php:
        image: php7-custom-conf
        volumes:
            - ./code/public_html:/code
        links:
            - db
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
        - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbrootpass
         MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
         MYSQL_USER: dbuser
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
```

Toda ajuda é bem vinda é fim de semestre e realmente não consigo enxergar o erro, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente era um erro de permissão de diretório, consegui contornar o problema usando o `chmod 0755 ./code/public_html` aparentemente as definições de acesso do linux permitiam apenas o meu usuário, e com esse comando eu libero leitura e escrita para o dono do arquivo, usuários do mesmo grupo e outros usuários.

Fontes:
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Entendendo-as-permissoes-de-arquivos-(chmod)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053456/nginx-not-showing-index-php/47055492#47055492

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Usa outra imagem do nginx do docker, essas novas imagens são diferentes as configurações, teria que olhar na documentação.
Eu uso assim e funciona.

```
nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
phpfpm:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: no caso se eu acrescentar a parte do mysql vai sem nenhum problema não é?

Comment: Não, podes acrescentar o que for necessário nesse composer.
Fique a vontade, so coloquei a parte para resolver seu problema.